# API requests returning errors trying to access NestJS backend from Angular frontend

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs, ngxs, nrwl-nx

When making an API call to my NestJS app I'm receiving the following errors.

> core.js:6185 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://localhost:3333/api/product-index", ok: false, …}

and

> GET https://localhost:3333/api/product-index net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

From looking into Nest, Angular and NGXS individually and the suggested ways to go about things I have everything set up properly.  The only thing I could think to do was tinker with the references to `localhost:3333/api` to see if maybe I'm targeting a location that doesn't exist.  I noticed when I change `https` to `http` I get a CORS error that doesn't go away even when including `enableCors()` in the `main.ts` file.  I've watched and read a few tutorials connecting NestJS to Angular and once they get the files set up it just works.  I've been reviewing the tutorial on nrwl's site and I have everything set up properly as far as I can see.

This is what the `main.ts` file looks like in my Nest app

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const globalPrefix = 'api';
  app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix);
  const port = process.env.port || 3333;
  await app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port + '/' + globalPrefix);
  });
}

bootstrap();
```

the `serve` data for my frontend project in the `angular.json` file looks like this

```
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
    "browserTarget": "cre8or-maker:build",
    "proxyConfig": "apps/cre8or-maker/proxy.conf.json"
}
```

the `proxy.conf.json` file in my frontend project looks like this

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "https://localhost:3333",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

I have a service file in my NGXS module that makes a request to the `product-index` controller in the Nest App which looks like this

```
export class ProductIndexService{

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

    private readonly URL: string = 'https://localhost:3333/api';




    public fetchProductIndexList():Observable<CattegoryIndexItem[]>{
        const path: string = this.URL + '/product-index';

        return this.httpClient.get(path) as Observable<CattegoryIndexItem[]>;
    }
}
```

My `environments/environments.ts` file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: '/api'
};
```

My `environments/environments.prod.ts` file

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

As I mentioned before I tried things like adding and removing `/api` from the path and going back and forth between `http` and `https` and it just won't work.  I can successfully call the `product-index` controller from `localhost:3333` so I know everything is set up properly in Nest, from the paths shown in the error it looks like I'm targeting it properly from my NGXS state. What's the problem here?  What am I missing or else should I look at?

Comment: Just a guess. Nest has a problem with self signed certificates. Try to add this in your server side code: process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

Comment: what file should I add that to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around I came across an alternative method for enabling cors in our app which is to apply it to the `create()` function of the `NestFactory` in the `main.ts` file like this

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {cors: true});
```

This made the errors go away.  I don't know why there's a difference between this and `app.enableCors()`.  I'm using Angular 9.1 so maybe there's something under the hood with it preventing Nest from making the connection.