# Should we be using http or https in our API request while building our applications?

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to figure out why I can't make api requests to my backend Nest App from Angular and one suggestion given was to change `http` to `https`.  In all the examples I'm coming across they're using `http` and it works just fine.  Is there anything that makes a difference in which we should use or should they both essentially work while creating our apps?

Comment: Should work with http or https.  What error are u getting?

Comment: I made a post last night about it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963983/api-requests-returning-errors-trying-to-access-nestjs-backend-from-angular-front?noredirect=1#comment107869766_60963983

still stuck there, just poking around at anything I can think of separately from that.

Comment: Looking at the other post, I think you need to enable cors on the backend, not the frontend. The other thing you could be hitting is that the cert isn't being trusted. if you navigate to one of your GET endpoints in the browser or use postman, what happens?

Comment: in the browser I can call the data without a problem at `localhost:3333` and as of right now I have this in my main.ts file in the nest app
`app.enableCors({origin: ['*'], credentials: true});
  app.use((res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });` 
and it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for dev purposes, I would use `http` for my backend service. It makes is much easier in the long run. However, for production systems `https` should be used.
The way all the projects I've worked on are designed, is that the backend service keeps using `http` and there's a load balancer in front of it which exposes the backend as `https` endpoint (e.g. [implementation via NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/) and some [more information from F5](https://www.f5.com/services/resources/glossary/ssl-termination))

This however, does not take care of [`CORS`](https://enable-cors.org/index.html). The steps to enable `CORS` depend on the backend technology . Using [`NestJS`](https://nestjs.com/), the steps are described [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security#cors):

> To enable CORS, call the `enableCors()` method on the Nest application object.
>
> ```js
> const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
> app.enableCors();
> await app.listen(3000);
> ```
>
> The `enableCors()` method takes an optional configuration object argument.
>   The available properties of this object are described in the official [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options) documentation.
>   Alternatively, enable CORS via the `create()` method's options object.
>   Set the `cors` property to `true` to enable CORS with default settings.
>   Alternatively, pass a [CORS configuration object](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options) as the cors property
>   value to customize its behavior.
>
> ```js
> const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
> await app.listen(3000);
> ```